# Is there a way to halt loading a react app until authentication status is resolved?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

I'm loading a react app that has a root component App.js which is determining if an authenticated user exists through a central redux store, but the problem is it takes a fraction of a second to resolve. Until then the user is getting a flash of the login page even if the user is logged in, which I'm sure counts as bad user experience. Is there a way to not show *anything at all* until the the status is resolved. I'm attaching a code snippet.

```
function App(props) {
  const cookies = new Cookies();
  const { user } = props;
  if (cookies.get("authToken") === "null" || cookies.get("authToken") === undefined) {
    //console.log("no valid token");
  } else {
    if (user === null) {
      props.fetchLoggedInUser(cookies.get("authToken"));
    }
  }

  const isLoggedIn = user ? (
    <div className="App s12 l12 m12">
      <Navbar user={user}/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={() => (<Home user={user} />)}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/create_blog" component={() => (<CreateBlog user={user} />)}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/edit_profile" component={() => (<EditProfile user={user} />)}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar user={null}/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={() => (<Home user={null} />)}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/log_in" component={LogIn}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/sign_up" component={SignUp}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {isLoggedIn}
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      authError: state.auth.authError,
      token: state.auth.token,
      user: state.auth.user
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchLoggedInUser: (token) => dispatch(fetchLoggedInUser(token))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: There should be multiple ways to do this. You could try wrapping this part in another component, which renders nothing (or whatever you want) while sending the auth request. As soon as you are authorized, you load another component.

Comment: Just use a third "middle" state that is neither authenticated nor unauthenticated and conditionally render null until ready. It'd be a lot more clean create a `PrivateRoute` component that checks the auth state from your redux store for what the use has access to. For components like `Home` they can also check the current user from redux state. FYI, you should ***really*** not do `component={() => (<Home user={null} />)}` as this creates a new component each time the parent component rerenders, use the `render` prop instead, i.e. `render={() => (<Home user={null} />)}`, it's what it's for.

Comment: Oh thanks for such prompt answers. Now it sounds so obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a state variable isLoading (or with ay name you want). set its initial value to true.

```
if (isLoading) {
    return '';
} else {
  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    {isLoggedIn}
  </BrowserRouter>
 );
}
```

Once you get the value of isLoggedIn you can set back isLoading to false and react will rerender.